# mimic target="_new" for a button

Tags: javascript, html

lets say we have a link

```
<a href="/something" target="_new">blah</a>
```

and now i want a button to do the same thing as the link does, without using jquery.

does anyone have experience with something like that?

**edit:**

This needs to be a link that uses target="_new" because doing that instead of a straight popup is a workaround for some problems IE6 has with opening downloads in popups.

In short: i have a very good reason for using a link, but i started out with a button, so it would be good to not have to style my link to look like button if i can do something with javascript.

Comment: are you attempting to submit a form, with the form data sent to the new window?

Comment: i am attempting to open a download window without navigating from current page, and without using a popup window (js)

Comment: Why support IE6? There are two newer versions of this browsers. People need to wake up (and bosses get kicked in their ar**s)

Comment: because our customers have IE6, and they pay us money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No scripting required:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form method="get" action="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
   <div><button type="submit">Click me</button></div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [window.open()](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en-us&q=window.open&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)  You may experience problems with pop-up blockers in browsers.

Comment: Do they actually block the pop-up if the users clicks himself? I guess the browsers can differ between a "real" click and a simulated event. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('/something');" value="blah" />
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('/something');">blah</button>
```